# Deleting a mongodb subdocument inside another that is inside another?

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I have read other posts similar to this one, but since I am new to mongodb and the depth of the subdocument that I have is more then already addressed, I have to ask this question here. My document is as follows:

```
{
"_id" : "57bae0ad7bbba417fcaec4ca",
"spUserProfile" : null,
"spLinkedBusinesses" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "57bae0ad7bbba417fcaec4c9",
        "businessDocuments" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "57bae0fb7bbba417fcaec4cc",
                "documentPath" : "/docs/doc1.pdf",
                "documentName" : "Doc Hey",
                "documentType" : "DPF",
                "documentUploadDateTime" : ISODate("2016-08-22T11:24:43.061Z")
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : "57bae0fd7bbba417fcaec4cd",
                "documentPath" : "/docs/doc_mute.pdf",
                "documentName" : "Agreements IMP",
                "documentType" : "PDF",
                "documentUploadDateTime" : ISODate("2016-08-22T11:24:45.229Z")
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : "57bae0ff7bbba417fcaec4ce",
                "documentPath" : "/docs/accounts1.xls",
                "documentName" : "Expenses 1",
                "documentType" : "XLS",
                "documentUploadDateTime" : ISODate("2016-08-22T11:24:47.066Z")
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I have to delete the businessDocuments with id "57bae0fd7bbba417fcaec4cd" (using c# mongodb driver code), the collection is called RefUsers.

PS: I cant use the legacy C# mongodb drivers, so no use of the Query class.

thanks.

Comment: holy cows, got a tumbleweed badge for this, come on ppl!

Comment: Why just not read whole document, remove it with C# and save it again?

Comment: that is not an efficient way to update a document.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into $pull to remove documents from an embedded array

[Pull MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

ElemMatch will also be useful to you here if you are wanting to identify items within embedded arrays

[ElemMatch MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)